# Multiple users working remote on one mac?

Tags: windows, development, remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

we want to develop some iOS apps in our company. Since we use windows-pcs, we think about buying only one Mac and all working remotely from our windows machines on this single Mac. Is this possible? What type of Mac do we need for this scenario (Mac Mini or something bigger?). It would be enough, if only two users could connect at the same time to the mac.
Or do we have to buy a Mac for every developer in out team?

Thanks
Konrad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried some development to a remote Mac once. It was a terrible experience. Even over a LAN, the latency of the display update speed was maddening in what should be an instant-feedback development UI.

You could maybe try using virtual machines on the Mac Mini (I don't know how this would affect licensing, you'd probably have to buy another OSX per virtual machine) which would get around not being able to run more than one iOS Simulator as mentioned in the previous answer). While Xcode is a bit of a resource hog I think you could get away with it if its just two users.

I agree that a Mac Mini per developer is the sanest solution for your wallet and the kindest one for your developers though.

Answer (score 4):

If your plan is development using Xcode , then forget about multiple users on a single mac, because of 2 reasons

1. Multiple instances of XCode will make the system slow ,
2. even if you solve issue 1 buying adding lots of RAM and a powerful processor, the iOS simulator won't allow us to run more than 1 instance at a time.

So developers will face issue while developing. The best option for you for to reduce initial cost is go for multiple mac mini's with non-Apple displays and keyboard.

Hope this helps